# iOS UIImageView animationImages display remote pictures

Tags: uiimageview

I have three urls just like "http://xxx.x.xx.xx:8180/admin/upload/advert/advert_img.jpg",

they are pictures in the remote server.

And I have an UIImageView, I want to use:

```
_imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0, 504.0, 320.0, 40.0)];
NSArray *images = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:[UIImage imageNamed:@"advert_img"],[UIImage imageNamed:@"img01"],[UIImage imageNamed:@"img02"], nil];
_imageView.animationImages = images;
_imageView.animationDuration = 15;
[_imageView startAnimating];
```

to display these pictures. How can I do this? Thank you very much.

Comment: Hello there any solution i am trying to do the same

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try this :

```
    NSArray *frames = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
       [UIImage imageWithName:@"advert_img.png"],
       [UIImage imageWithName:@"img01.png"],
       [UIImage imageWithName:@"img02.png"],
       nil];

       UIImageView *animatedIMvw = [[UIImageView alloc] init];
       animatedIMvw.animationImages = frames;
       [animatedIMvw startAnimating];
```